# How to detect while carbon starting or stopping

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I used Runtime.getRuntime().exec() to start external program in GREG handler, and get its pid. But how I can detect when the GREG stopping or restarting , that I can stop or restart the external program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do execute some custom logic during startup or shutdown phases you can use handlers provided in org.wso2.carbon.core package

e.g.

ServerStartupHandler - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.4.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/core/ServerStartupHandler.java

ServerShutdownHandler - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.4.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/core/ServerShutdownHandler.java

ServerRestartHandler - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.4.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/core/ServerRestartHandler.java

Also you may use https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.4.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/core/ServerStartupObserver.java to listen to startup events

Answer (score 1):

There is no documented mechanism of doing this. There are some internal mechanisms within the OSGi space where the components can define dependancies to detest if those are started. However, I do not think those are exposed to handler API.

One way to do is to check if you can access a resource successfully from within the handler, and if so, then start the program.